# rutas PHP en alojamiento web

Tags: php, dompdf

ya hace tiempo que no utilizo servidores de alojamiento web y ahora, me encuentro con un problema...

el siguiente código funciona perfectamente con Xampp en mi servidor, en cambio, si lo paso a un servidor web de otro proveedor, tengo un error 500.

tengo la intuición de que el problema viene por el manejo de las rutas, la libreria EzPdf, con la cual me manejo bastante bien, tampoco me funciona... he probado de todo y no funciona... a ver si me guiais por el buen camino.... Gracias....

```
<?php

require_once 'libs/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
ob_start();
include "imprimefactura.php";
$html = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=facturapdf.pdf");
echo $dompdf->output();
?>
```

bueno, si modifico la ruta a 'imprimefactura.php", ya me abre un pdf pero vacío....vamos caminando...

```
include "/imprimefactura.php";
```

Parece que la solución mas rápida es cambiarlo de directorio, y vá funcionando...Pero....como siempre, mi vida es un desconcierto, ahora necesito pasar un parametro... y ya sabes....no funciona....

```
include "imprimefactura.php?id=16";
```

Perdón por el tostón....pero me estoy desneuronando...

Comment: Revisa los archivos logs o habilita `display_errors` para saber que mensaje de error te envía

Comment: Revisa del `phpinfo();` el valor de Apache Environment > DOCUMENT_ROOT. Y coméntanos dónde se encuentran `imprimefatura.php` y `libs` respecto a esa ruta.